# TabBarView inside Sliver with StickyHeader

Tags: flutter

I have made this layout so far using CustomScrollView and Sticky Header

https://i.stack.imgur.com/piwya.jpg

What I want to achieve is that the content below the tabs should not scroll unless there is extra content available. Also, after scrolling, the content should not go behind the sticky header.

My Code so far.

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
    toolbarHeight: getHeight() * (1 / 11),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: getPaddings(),
    child: DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: getHeight() * (3 / 11),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          SliverStickyHeader(
            header: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: getHeight() * (1 / 11),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "TEXT",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 32,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: getHeight() * (1 / 11),
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  child: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          'TITLE1',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          'TITLE2',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          'TITLE3',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            sliver: SliverFillRemaining(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(50),
                        vertical: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        RoundedPicture(),
                        FittedBox(
                          child: Text("Hello World",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 40)),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 20),
                                  text: 'Info1:  ',
                                  children: [
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: "123",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: kSecondaryColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                            ),
                            RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 20),
                                  text: 'Info2:  ',
                                  children: [
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: "abcd",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: kSecondaryColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                            ),
                            RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 20),
                                  text: 'Info3:  ',
                                  children: [
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: "xyz",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: kSecondaryColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("TITLE2"),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("TITLE3"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

To achieve the required layout, I tried using TabBarView inside different slivers i.e SliverList and SliverToBoxAdapter but they all resulted in an error because TabBarView doesn't have a predefined height.

Answer (score 13):

Here is my implementation.
Because there are no method related to size, I just set a value myself.

- Stack

  - DefaultTabController

    - NestedScrollView

      - SliverAppBar
      - SliverPersistentHeader
      - SliverPersistentHeader
      - TabBarView
  - Container // For back button

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(initialIndex: 0, length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  double getHeight() {
    return 800;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            DefaultTabController(
              length: 3,
              child: NestedScrollView(
                headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
                  return [
                    SliverAppBar(
                      expandedHeight: 200.0,
                      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(),
                    ),
                    SliverPersistentHeader(
                      pinned: true,
                      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                        minHeight: 90,
                        maxHeight: 90,
                        child: Container(
                          height: getHeight() * (1 / 11),
                          width: double.infinity,
                          color: Colors.green[200],
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "TEXT",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 32,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SliverPersistentHeader(
                      pinned: true,
                      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                        minHeight: 90,
                        maxHeight: 90,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.green[200],
                          child: TabBar(
                            controller: _tabController,
                            tabs: [
                              Tab(
                                child: Text(
                                  'TITLE1',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Tab(
                                child: Text(
                                  'TITLE2',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Tab(
                                child: Text(
                                  'TITLE3',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ];
                },
                body: TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 600),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            // RoundedPicture(),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.favorite,
                              color: Colors.pink,
                              size: 150.0,
                              semanticLabel:
                                  'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                            ),
                            FittedBox(
                              child: Text("Hello World",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 40)),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                RichText(
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 20),
                                      text: 'Info1:  ',
                                      children: [
                                        TextSpan(
                                          text: "123",
                                          style: TextStyle(),
                                        ),
                                      ]),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                RichText(
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 20),
                                      text: 'Info2:  ',
                                      children: [
                                        TextSpan(
                                          text: "abcd",
                                          style: TextStyle(),
                                        ),
                                      ]),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                RichText(
                                  text: TextSpan(
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 20),
                                      text: 'Info3:  ',
                                      children: [
                                        TextSpan(
                                          text: "xyz",
                                          style: TextStyle(),
                                        ),
                                      ]),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 600),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 600),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text("TITLE2"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 600),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 600),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text("TITLE3"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 90,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate({
    @required this.minHeight,
    @required this.maxHeight,
    @required this.child,
  });
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => math.max(maxHeight, minHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your code looks good but it also has the same issue which I was facing. First of all, the screen should not be scrolling unless there is extra content available which there isn't. And secondly, even if it does scroll, the content should atleast not go behind the sticky header unless the content of list is greater than the available size.

Comment: I changed to implement what you want. Wrapped SingleChildScrollView and Container and added a bottom padding as much as header size for contents scrolling.

Comment: I think you didn't understood my concern. Check this layout which I made with the code below. https://imgur.com/NkzJ7vi
The first tab and the third tab don't scroll because there isn't any extra content.
The second tab scrolls only to the extent of displaying the extra content. It doesn't goes all the way up behind the persistent header.

I changed the scroll physics to bouncing so you can see what is happening. If I change it to clamp, the first and third tab wont scroll at all, only the second tab will scroll.

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding. You means that although I changed and it can scroll without extra content, it is not what you want.

Comment: I *don't* want it to scroll without the extra content. My initial layout was also scrolling without the extra content. Still, thanks for the code, gives me a new perspective and ideas for solving issues.

Comment: @HuzaifaImran "Sorry for the late response. Your code looks good but it also has the same issue which I was facing. First of all, the screen should not be scrolling unless there is extra content available which there isn't. And secondly, even if it does scroll, the content should atleast not go behind the sticky header unless the content of list is greater than the available size." So did u find a solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

After finding no possible solution, I decided to implement my own tab bar view instead of using the default one. The solution isn't as fancy since the transition of tabs is done by changing the current page number and rebuilding the widget but solves the issue. I used a gesture detector for allowing users to swipe the page.

```
          GestureDetector(
           onHorizontalDragEnd: (dragDetails) {
             if (dragDetails.primaryVelocity != 0) {
               final int val = dragDetails.primaryVelocity.sign.toInt();
               if (currentPage - val >= 0 &&
                   currentPage - val < tabController.length)
                 tabController.animateTo(currentPage - val);
             }
           },
           child: CustomScrollView(
             shrinkWrap: true,
             controller: scrollController,
             slivers: [
               SliverToBoxAdapter(
                 child: LogoContainer(),
               ),
               SliverStickyHeader(
                 header: Column(
                   children: [
                     NameContainer(text: 'TEXT'),
                     Container(
                       height: 60,
                       color: kSecondaryColor,
                       child: TabBar(
                         controller: tabController,
                         tabs: [
                           Tab(
                             child: Text(
                               'TITLE1',
                               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                             ),
                           ),
                           Tab(
                             child: Text(
                               'TITLE2',
                               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                             ),
                           ),
                           Tab(
                             child: Text(
                               'TITLE3',
                               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                             ),
                           ),
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
                 sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                   child: ConstrainedBox(
                     constraints:
                         BoxConstraints(minHeight: getHeight() * (6 / 11)),
                     child: [
                       Column(
                         children: [
                           RoundedPicture(),
                           FittedBox(
                             child: Text(
                               'HELLO WORLD',
                               style: TextStyle(
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                   color: Colors.black,
                                   fontSize: 40),
                             ),
                           ),
                           SizedBox(
                             height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                           ),
                           Column(
                             children: [
                               ProfileInfoText(
                                 title: 'INFO1',
                                 text: 'abcd',
                               ),
                               SizedBox(
                                 height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                               ),
                               ProfileInfoText(
                                 title: 'INFO2',
                                 text: '123',
                               ),
                               SizedBox(
                                 height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                               ),
                               ProfileInfoText(
                                 title: 'INFO3',
                                 text: 'xyz',
                               ),
                             ],
                           ),
                         ],
                       ),
                       Center(
                         child: Text("TITLE2"),
                       ),
                       Center(
                         child: Text("TITLE3"),
                       ),
                     ].elementAt(currentPage),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
```

I also used scroll controller to animate the list back to top when changing the tabs to give it a smooth look.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this)
      ..addListener(() async {
        await scrollController.animateTo(
          0,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        );
        setState(() {
          currentPage = tabController.index;
        });
      });
  }
```